# how to make a textarea in which it is possible to write at any positon inside it?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am trying to make a textarea in which it is possible to click anywhere and write. i tried making text areas dynamically on touch position but after making it, it is not possible to select the whole matter in both text areas,so its not serving the purpose. Can anyone tell if we can do something about this?

Answer (score 2):

You could just fill the textarea with spaces. Every time there's an input you replace the space before the cursor with your input.